# ToolTip is not working as per browser resolution

Tags: html, css, angularjs

If I hover textbox tootltip will visible on the right side. But when I hover on the last element, it is not working properly and it is hiding.

Please look at the following fiddle,

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/myd7L34e/)

The fiddle code has written in jquery. I want in **angularjs**.

**If I have more textboxes, the horizantal scroll will come. That time, last card in the sense (div width), when it reach last at the div the tooltip is not visible.**

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var className = $(this).val();
    var position;
    switch (className) {
      case 'right':
            position = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center' };
            break;
    }
    position.collision = 'none';
    
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
    $('input[type="text"]').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', className);
});

$('#options').buttonset();
$('input[type="text"]').tooltip();
$('input[value="right"]').trigger('change');
```

```css
body { padding: 20px; }


.test{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-flex;
  position : absolute;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

input[type="text"] { margin: 50px 0 0 0px; width:177px;}

.ui-tooltip {
    background: #666;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.ui-tooltip-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
}
.ui-tooltip-content::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
.right .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: 18px;
    left: -10px;
    border-color: transparent #666;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.left .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: 18px;
    right: -10px;
    border-color: transparent #666;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}
.top .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 72px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;    
}
.bottom .ui-tooltip-content::after {
    top: -10px;
    left: 72px;
    border-color: #666 transparent;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
    <label for="right">Right</label><input type="radio" value="right" name="option" id="right" checked />
</div>

<div class="test">
    <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
    <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
    <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
    <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
    <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
     <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
      <input type="text" title="I am a tooltip!" />
</div>
```

I want to show tooltip, if it will reach last right, it should show as left side, otherwise as default it should show right side.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Hi, you should be able to just check for the screen width and the offset of the input element.Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5Lrxpbfw/

Comment: The tooltips all work fine if you scroll, not sure where the last tooltip isn't working. I think your problem is the horizontal scrolling which you want to eliminate. For that you will either define a responsive layout or you will use relative units for the size of your inputs. At the moment you are sizing them 177px which means that when the container runs out of available space will scroll them. You can deal with this with a flexbox or grid layout, you can use a framework like bootstrap or you can add breakpoints to your css. Sorry can't help with Angular syntax.

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: I am not sure if I got this correctly but if you use flex-wrap your components will wrap when the available space runs out. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ftd6Lqx7/

Comment: @rodcunha Please check the fiddle once. I am sorry this is not working. Even tooltip style also changed.